# Why is removeChild() not working in my code? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

So I'm creating a search website where the user enters a part of a name or a full name and then presses a button. And based on the string entered, it displays a hint of names of actors that contain the string or sub-string. The names are stored in a mysql database.

I was able to accomplish all of that by using ajax to interact with php and php to interact with mysql database. However, if the user enters nothing, it's supposed to display nothing.

So I though of just deleting all names when the field text is empty (in other words, I just delete all p elements of a div).

That's where the problem is. Even though I used `element.removeChild()`, It doesn't delete anything. Instead, even when the string is empty and the user presses the button, it keeps the same info from the previous search. I already searched on similar questions about `removeChild()`, but none of the answers or hints I found have worked for me.

Here is the javascript and html code below.

```js
        var array = [];
        var str = "";
        var clicked_id = "";
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];
        var actors = document.getElementById('actors');
        var roles = document.getElementById('roles');

        actors.addEventListener("click", function(){
            getData(this.id);
        }, false);
        roles.addEventListener("click", function(){
           getData(this.id); 
        }, false);
        
        function getData(myid) {
            str = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
            clicked_id = myid;
            var id = "roles";
            console.log(clicked_id);
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    array = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    
                    var element = document.createElement('div');
                    element.id = "mydiv";

                    if (str == "" && element.hasChildNodes() != null) {
                        while (element.hasChildNodes()) {
                            element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            var p = document.createElement('p');
                            p.append(array[i]);
                            element.append(p);
                        }
                        body.append(element);
                    }
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "controller.php?q="+str , true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h2>Search for either all roles or all actors in the database imdb_small</h2>
    <hr> Search string <br>
    <input type="text" id="mytext"> <br>
    <input type="button" value="Actors" id="actors">
    <input type="button" value="Roles"  id="roles" > <br> <br>
    <hr> <br><br>
</body>
```

Comment: try after changing `if (str == "" && element.hasChildNodes() != null)` to `if (!str && element.hasChildNodes() != null)`

Comment: note: `element.hasChildNodes() != null` is always true

Comment: I just did that but nothing has changed. It still won't remove the elements

Comment: you are creating an empty div ... then immediately checking if it has children ... that's a little redundant, of course it has no children if you only just created it!

Comment: Even without element.hasChildNodes() != null  nothing changes. It still won't remove the children of element

Comment: note, `element.append` is not a function - you'r thinking of jquery

Comment: note 3: `document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];` is `document.body`

Comment: `Even though I used element.removeChild(), It doesn't delete anything` - because you're using `element.removeChild()` on a freshly created `element = document.createElement('div')` ... there is nothing to remove

Comment: But even when it has children, I mean when the user enters something, and then I the user enters an empty string, nothing happens.

Comment: you have an argument `myid` whose only use is to set the value of `clicked_id`, which is then never used. you also create a var `id` which is, again, never used ...

Comment: Nothing happens coz next time when user submits it again creates a div which has no child. The one which you are seeing it the older one of previous request

Comment: `But even when it has children` - **it never has children** ... a freshly created `element` using `document.createElement` is created with no children, ever, you've either removed too much from your actual code to show here, or you've missed a very important step

Comment: I'm fixing them according to your notes. But they are not fixing the actual problem behind removeChild() not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. All of your notes and ideas were helpful. I correct all places where you guys pointed out along with the solution posted below and it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
        var array = [];
        var str = "";
        var clicked_id = "";
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];
        var actors = document.getElementById('actors');
        var roles = document.getElementById('roles');

        actors.addEventListener("click", function(){
            getData(this.id);
        }, false);
        roles.addEventListener("click", function(){
           getData(this.id); 
        }, false);
        
        function getData(myid) {
            str = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
            clicked_id = myid;
            var id = "roles";
            console.log(clicked_id);
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    array = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    
                    // Check for an existing mydiv first here, before creating a new one
                    // If it exists then get it and check its child nodes

                    var element = document.getElementById('#mydiv');
                    element = element ? element : document.createElement('div');
                    element.id = "mydiv";

                    if (str == "" && element.hasChildNodes() != null) {
                        while (element.hasChildNodes()) {
                            element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            var p = document.createElement('p');
                            p.append(array[i]);
                            element.append(p);
                        }
                        body.append(element);
                    }
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "controller.php?q="+str , true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h2>Search for either all roles or all actors in the database imdb_small</h2>
    <hr> Search string <br>
    <input type="text" id="mytext"> <br>
    <input type="button" value="Actors" id="actors">
    <input type="button" value="Roles"  id="roles" > <br> <br>
    <hr> <br><br>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You solution was very helpful and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="demon";

    //CREATE CONNECTION
    $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    //CHECK CONNECTION
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("connection failed:".$conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql="delete from category where SUBCATEGORY_ID='".$_GET["id"]."'";

    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    if ($result===TRUE) 
    {
        echo"RECORD DELETED SUCCESSFULLY";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR:".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).